# php не обрабатывает переменные

Tags: php, htmlspecialchars

Почему при выводе текста, например, "`$value`" из базы MySQL в `echo` выводится тупо текст "`$value`", а не его значение выраженное выше в коде "$value = '1'"?

Ведь, по сути, он должен писать 1 вместо `$value`...

Comment: Добро пожаловать на ru.SO! При создании вопроса вам стоит приводить код, соответствующий [**минимальному** примеру](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), необходимому для воспроизведения проблемы. Вряд ли кто-то захочет ковыряться в той портянке, что вы привели.

Comment: Ковырятся не заставляю, просто спросил почему выводится текст а не переменная, а код оставил наоборот для большего удобства что-бы никто не указывал на банальные ошибки и видел сразу в чем дело.

Comment: Два минуса вам как бы намекают, что вы сделали что-то не так.

Comment: Ну и пусть намекают, лично я считаю что ничего плохого в большом тексте нет, а те кто ставят минусы пусть и печатают вопросы формата: Че этат код у миня ни работаит? И выкладывают нерабочие обрубки кода.

Comment: Так если в mysql лежит строка "$value", то эта же строка и будет выведена. Вот если вы напишите $a = '$value' и выведете $a - опять же будет выведена строка $value.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

PHP вам ничего не должен.

Подстановка значений переменных в строку (*интерполяция*) происходит только если вы в явном виде определяете эту строку в коде. Если же вы получаете строку откуда-то еще (база данных, текстовый файл, переменные окружения и т.д.), то интерполяции не происходит. Строка остается "как есть".

**Что с этим делать?**

Можно попробовать интерпретировать строку, как PHP код, но это **очень плохая** идея. Вот пример:

```
// $template содержит строку 'echo $value;'
eval($template);
```

Проблема только в том, что строка `$template` должна содержать валидный PHP код. Ну и это очень большая потенциальная уязвимость.

Можно пытаться использовать регулярные выражения, для замены переменных на их значения, что тоже довольно грустно.

Правильнее всего, было бы использовать некие *плейсхолдеры* для переменных и динамически генерировать результат на основе контекста. В общем виде, это может выглядеть как-то так:

```
$template = '{{value}}';
$context = ['value' => 1];

// Выведет "1".
echo render($template, $context);
```

В пример выше, функция `render` - это некий *абстрактный* обработчик строки. И да, примерно так и работают шаблонизаторы.

Answer (score 0):

Из вопроса ничего не понятно. Вот простой пример вывода.

```
$value = 1;

echo '$value'; // выдаст $value т.к воспринимается не как переменная а как символы
echo "$value"; // выдаст 1 т.к это подобие кантотанации
echo $value; // выдаст 1 просто вывод переменной
```

Это  из того что я понял. Если ошибка состоит в том что у вас в базе лежит имя переменной как $value то это строка и ничего не понятного тут нет.

[Тут можно найти подробней](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.string.php).

Уважайте время людей которые хотят помочь вам решить вашу проблему соблюдайте [правила](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)